# Rake running wrong version with Rails vim plugin

Tags: vim, rake, bundler

I am using vim on Fedora with the Tim Pope Rail plugin - I want to run tests with :Rake
and I get an error with rake 0.9.3.beta.1   I know that bundle exec rake will cure this but I want to run my tests within vim - The Rails plugin docs seem to indicate that :Rake invokes bundle exec but it doesn't on my system

I have tried to remove rake 0.9.3.beta.1 without success

Anyone know a way to fix this?

I wouldn't mind just removing rake 0.9.3.beta.1 but gem uninstall won't do it

Answer (score 0):

Via rails.vim's doc:

```
:[range]Rake {targets}  Calls |:make!| {targets} (with 'makeprg' being rake,
        or `bundle exec rake` if bundler.vim is active)
```

Is [bundler.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler) active?

Comment: I have bundler vim and it works but I am not sure what active means the commands such a :Bundle and :Bopen work -